# How to solve a geometric problem about a triangle using GeometricSolveValues?

Tags: geometry, synthetic-geometry

I try to solve not so difficult geometric problem
from an exercise book on elementary math with 14.0 on Windows 10:

> Let a triangle $\triangle ABC$ be given and the area of $\triangle ABC$ be equal to $60$ and $\cos(\angle ACB)=\frac 5 {13}$ and the area of the inscribed circle be equal to $\frac {100\pi} 9$.
> Find the lengths of the sides $|AB|,|BC|,|AC|$.

Here is my unsuccessful attempt

```
ClearAll[a, b, c];
GeometricSolveValues[GeometricScene[{a, b, c}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
 PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}] == ArcCos[5/13],  Area[Triangle[{a, b, c}]] == 60, 
 Area[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == Pi*100/9}], {EuclideanDistance[a, b], 
 EuclideanDistance[c, b], EuclideanDistance[a, c]}]
```

which results in `{}` instead of `10, 13, 13`. The same happens with `PlanarAngle[c -> {a, b}] == (ArcCos[5/13]*180/Pi) °`.

How to solve it with Mathematica by using `GeometricSolveValues`, not solving a system of three equations in three unknowns?

Comment: @Domen: I prefer to formulate  "how to solve" over "how can I solve" since this is of a common interest.

Comment: For the $n$-th time: "How to ...?" is [not a grammatically correct](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/329439/do-how-to-questions-end-with-a-question-mark) question in English. Please stop putting question marks where they don't belong.

Comment: @Domen - it's they're question, they can frase it how they like.

Comment: _"How can I ...?"_, _"How do we ...?"_, _"How can ... be solved?"_ or _"How to ..."_ without a question mark. @JasonB., it is about the grammar, not phrasing. And the problem is not this particular question, it's dozens of other decades old questions to which this user constantly keeps putting question marks. That's the reason for my comment.

Comment: @Domen: I'd like to quote one of the answers in the linked thread "Contrary to what other answers assert, the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL 2002, ch. 10: §4.5) considers constructions like your example to be sentences, and they explicitly state that the expected punctuation is a question mark if these constructions are used as questions. For illustration, the CGEL uses the following two constructions (CGEL 2002: 873):

[i] What to do in the event of fire

[ii] How to persuade her to forgive him?".

Comment: @Domen: It should be noticed that no answer in the linked thread is accepted. In view of it your "For the n-th time: "How to ...?" is not a grammatically correct question in English. Please stop putting question marks where they don't belong" is your personal opinion.

Comment: `Solve[p == (x + y + z)/2 && 
  p*(p - x)*(p - y)*(p - z) == 60^2 && (60/p)^2*Pi == Pi*100/9 && 
  5/13
   == (x^2 + y^2 - z^2)/2/x/y && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {p, x, y, 
  z}, Reals]` works well.

Comment: @chuy: Thank you for the articles. As far as as I know English,  some articles in heads may be omitted. Do I have the right to preserve the question under consideration from further edits?

Comment: [CASE:5111372]  has been submitted by me.

Comment: I don't understand the vote to close the question because "The question is out of scope for this site. The answer to this question requires either advice from Wolfram support or the services of a professional consultant". I hope the correct answer can be done by `GeometricStep`s. Two small steps are better than one big step.

Comment: The trouble comes from `Area[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == Pi*100/9`. This shows where the trouble is: `Area[Insphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]] or Area[Circle[]]`, which is probably worth a note to Wolfram.  For this particular scenario, you can trivially recast the problem with: `GeometricSolveValues[GeometricScene[{a,b,c},{Triangle[{a,b,c}],PlanarAngle[{a,c,b}]==ArcCos[5/13],Area[Triangle[{a,b,c}]]==60,RegionMeasure[Insphere[{a,b,c}]]==20Pi/3}],{EuclideanDistance[a,b],EuclideanDistance[c,b],EuclideanDistance[a,c]}]`, which returns `{{13, 13, 10}}`

Comment: @chuy: Many thanks from me to you for the workaround. Can you kindly present it as an answer in order I'll accept it.

Comment: @chuy: `Map[Area[Disk @@ #] &, {Insphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]}]` results in `{\[Pi]/(2 (1 + Sqrt[2])^2)}`.

Comment: @Chuy: Unfortunately, `GeometricSolveValues[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}] == ArcCos[5/13], 
   Area[Triangle[{a, b, c}]] == 60, 
   Map[Area[Disk @@ #] &, {Insphere[{a, b, c}]}][[1]] == 
    100*Pi/9}], {EuclideanDistance[a, b], EuclideanDistance[c, b], 
  EuclideanDistance[a, c]}]` returns the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trouble comes from

```
Area[Insphere[{a, b, c}]] == Pi*100/9
```

This is going to be a condition that cannot be reconciled because Wolfram Language is going to evantually turn the `Insphere` into a `Sphere` and a 2D sphere is going to have an undefined area. See:

```
Area[Insphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]
```

or

```
Area[Circle[]]
```

The function [`InscribedBall`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InscribedBall.html) can be used to create an inscribed Ball, but it isn't a supported object that GeometricScene can handle in this version. Asking for support for InscribedBall in GeometricScene is probably worth a note to Wolfram.

For this particular scenario, you can avoid this issue by trivially recasting the problem to:

```
GeometricSolveValues[
    GeometricScene[{a, b, c},
        {
            Triangle[{a, b, c}],
            PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}],== ArcCos[5 / 13],
            Area@Triangle[{a, b, c}] == 60,
            RegionMeasure@Insphere[{a, b, c}] == 20 * Pi / 3
        }
    ],
    {
        EuclideanDistance[a, b],
        EuclideanDistance[c, b],
        EuclideanDistance[a, c]
    }
]
```

which returns

```
{{13, 13, 10}}
```

Comment: It should be noticed that `Map[Area[Disk @@ #] &, {Insphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]}][[1]]` outputs `\[Pi]/(2 (1 + Sqrt[2])^2)`, but `GeometricSolveValues[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   PlanarAngle[{a, c, b}] == ArcCos[5/13], 
   Area[Triangle[{a, b, c}]] == 60, 
   Map[Area[Disk @@ #] &, {Insphere[{a, b, c}]}][[1]] == 
    100*Pi/9}], {EuclideanDistance[a, b], EuclideanDistance[c, b], 
  EuclideanDistance[a, c]}]` returns the input.

Comment: Much simpler is `Area[Ball @@ Insphere[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]]`, but as you say that doesn't help because that transformation needs to take place downstream in the evaluation process.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved rather trivially, without using complex functions like "GeometricSolveValues".

First, calculate the angle at point C: pC and the radius of the incircle: ri. Then using 3 different formula for the area of a triangle, we can get the sides: a,b,c:

```
pC = ArcCos[5/13];
ri = Sqrt[100/9];

eq = {60 == 1/2  a  b  Sin[pC],
   60 == ri (a + b + c)/2,
   60 == 1/4  Tan[pC]  (a^2 + b^2 - c^2),
   {a, b, c} > 0
   };
sol = Solve[eq, {a, b, c}][[1]]

{a -> 10, b -> 13, c -> 13}
```

To check, we use a formula for the incircle radius and compare it against: ri:

```
s = (a + b + c)/2 /. sol;
(Sqrt[(s - a) (s - b) (s - c)/s] /. sol  ) == ri

True
```

Comment: Did you read "How to solve it with Mathematica by using `GeometricSolveValues`, not solving a system of three equations in three unknowns?" in the question and my comment  "`Solve[p == (x + y + z)/2 &&    p*(p - x)*(p - y)*(p - z) == 60^2 && (60/p)^2*Pi == Pi*100/9 &&    5/13    == (x^2 + y^2 - z^2)/2/x/y && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {p, x, y,    z}, Reals]` works well" to my question before having submitted your attempt to answer?

Comment: I think you don't understand the aim of the question to test the `GeometricSolveValues` command.